# Quoting: original vs different source?

Tags: quotes, quotations

On my bag, I have a quote: *Be not inhospitable to strangers lest they be angels in disguise.* I thought the quote was from Shakespeare on my bag.

However, it is also a quote from the bible.

If I repeat the quote, am I quoting the bible or my bag?

Comment: Is this an academic question or a hypothetical? Is there a particular citation style that you're following?

Comment: I'd say that you're quoting your bag and your bag is quoting the Bible; or that you are quoting the Bible indirectly.

Comment: anotherdave: It was in casual conversation

Comment: hellion: thanks, if you had to be specific and say either bag or bible which do you think is better?

Comment: If you don't know the original source and only know it from your bag, then you're quoting your bag.

Comment: When I quote it, I am quoting YOU, since I did not look it up in my Bible or my Shakespeare. I guess that makes YOU the erudite one!

Comment: Note the qualification in this definition [(AHD)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/quote):  To repeat or copy the words of (another), usually with acknowledgment of the source. So, you're quoting the 'source' of the message that you mention. This may (as here) not be the primary source (possibly Paul under inspiration, for the original Greek version) and it would be best to give the most ancient reference you are aware of. You would disambiguate in conversation: 'In Hebrews it says. . .' / 'On my bag there's a maxim written: . . .'.

Answer (score 1):

The Bible was written long before the time of Shakespeare.  Hebrews 13:2 (KJV):

> Be not forgetful to entertain strangers: for thereby some have entertained angels unawares.

**George Whitman**, an American, bought *Shakespeare & Company*, a fabled English-language bookstore on the Left Bank in Paris, and a magnet for writers, poets and tourists for close to 60 years.

He welcomed visitors with large-print messages on the walls. “Be not inhospitable to strangers, lest they be angels in disguise,” was one. Though it has been [mistakenly](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/12/15/books/george-whitman-paris-bookseller-and-cultural-beacon-is-dead-at-98.html?scp=1&sq=George%20Whitman%20obituary&st=cse) attributed to Yeats, it was not written by him, but by Mr. Whitman, who was quoting the Bible.

That may be why the name *Shakespeare* was on your bag.